# How to write an instance of Parcelable class 'A' which contains an instance of parcelable class 'B', to Parcel from class 'B'

Tags: java, android, recursion, parcelable

I have some problems with using parcelables for my *Android* app.
I have a custom class named `Transport`, which contains a bunch of `RoutePoint`-instances which has been loaded from a file and saved in an array.

Both the classes `implements Parcelable`, because I want to pass the `Transport` object, which contains `RoutePoint` objects, between multiple activities.

This brings a problem, because inside of each `RoutePoint` object, I have a `Transport` object used to tell which transport is the parent for the `RoutePoint`.

Pretend that I have these classes:

`Transport`:

```
public class Transport implements Parcelable
{
    private RoutePoint[] points;

    public Transport()
    {
        // Here the array is initialized
    }

    // Methods needed because of the Parcelable interface
}
```

`RoutePoint`:

```
public class RoutePoint implements Parcelable
{
    private Transport parent;

    public RoutePoint(Transport parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    // Methods needed because of the Parcelable interface
}
```

When the `Transport` class is written to a `Parcel`, I write all the `RoutePoint`s from the array to the parcel too.

When the `RoutePoint` class is written to a `Parcel`, I write the parent `Transport` to the parcel too.

This causes a "recursive call", and a `StackOverflowException`:

1. The `Transport` writes a `RoutePoint` to the `Parcel`.
2. The `RoutePoint` writes the parent `Transport` to the `Parcel`.
3. The parent `Transport` writes a `RoutePoint` to the `Parcel`.
4. Back to step 2.

---

**I wonder** how I can get around this problem, and pass the `Transport` class between activities, and passing the `parent` object in the `RoutePoint` class in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all `RoutePoint` instances are always contained inside a `Transport` instance, you can fix it by not serializing RoutePoint.parent, but rather setting it when you deserialize Transport.

So, when you deserialize a Transport instance, deserialize the RoutePoints, then call a `setTransport` method on those RoutePoint instances and set the parent.

Comment: Thanks! The simple, and many times pretty obvious, solutions seems to be hard to find... :)

Answer (score 0):

Having Circular reference like that is not really a good idea from GC perspective too. I would suggest you have one way reference and use other data structure like BiMap etc to have those relationship defined. 
One way is to create an Empty constructor in RoutePoint and only parcel other item except for the parent. In Transport, while reading from parcel, set its reference later. Hope this makes sense.